# How to make commits on protected branch in git?

Tags: git, gitlab

My `master` branch in protected.

Just I want to make small(One line changes) commit on master.

I don't want to make a new branch and merge with master.

But i'm getting messages while push code on master:

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.
To https://gitlab.com/xyz/api_xyz.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/xyz/api_xyz.git'
```

**Is it permission problem?**

**Can I make a commit to the protected branch?**

Comment: Hi. Do you know what "protected branch" means?

Answer (score 1):

You can commit locally, but, by default, no one (with exceptions, see link below) is allowed to push to a protected branch. You can change this default behavior in the settings; see [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html):

Since GitLab 8.11, you can define which roles are allowed to push to a protected branch via `Settings`->`Repositories`->`Protected Branches`:
[image]

Alas, you should not carelessly commit and push to protected branches; they're mostly protected for a reason. Why not just create a merge request and lat your code be reviewed before it is merged?!

Answer (score 0):

In Gitlab only the project master can allow you to push in master, developpers have to issue merge request.

Go to Settings > Repository to change permissions or ask your project master to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html

Only Maintainer or Owner have **"Push to protected branches"** permission.

To protect a branch, you need to have at least **Maintainer/Owner permission** level. Note that the **master branch is protected by default**.

> Configuring protected branches To protect a branch, you need to have
>   at least Maintainer permission level. Note that the master branch is
>   protected by default.
>
> 1. Navigate to your project’s **Settings ➔ Repository**
> 2. Scroll to find the Protected branches section.
> 3. From the Branch dropdown menu, select the branch you want to protect and click Protect. In the screenshot below, we chose the
>      develop branch.